# Where would I ask a question about general computer systems?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where would I ask a question relating to general computer programming? Specifically, I am wondering about some exact technicalities of kernels, and if complete systems that have been programmed to use files, and then interface with higher-level graphical interfaces are kernels. This is in contrast to the standard definition of a kernel as an interface between physical hardware and software. If not, what term would I use?

Comment: might be worth extending your example in this question so that you get a better response.

Comment: I read your current question as _"Are operating systems that work with files and use a graphical user interfaces considered kernels?"_, which in my opinion is "unclear what you're asking". Can you show, for example by elaborating what you think is considered a kernel, what a kernel does, what the alternative would be and why exactly you're asking, that you understand a little bit what you're talking about so the answers can be factual?

Comment: CodeCaster, that was exactly what I intended for you to read. However, I have added a general definition, in the way I understand it, of a kernel.

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate! This is different. I am unsure, based on those definitions in the question that you marked my question as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest cs.stackexchange.com , programmers.stackexchange.com or area51.stackexchange.com for that.

It depends a lot, what is exactly your question. Cs has a scientific-mathematical direction, while programmers.stackexchange.com likes more questions from the "common experience" or even software project management side.

From the workings of the operating system kernels could be maybe serverfault.com also a good choice, although you must formulate your question to make it closely related to professional system administration.

And on area51.stackexchange.com, you can help to create new SE sites where you can ask, which is closed here as offtopic.

Comment: Thank you! However, we already have enough computer-related SE sites, it seems. :)

Comment: @LiamSchumm Not enough - sites with time tends to narrow their ontopic content, people tends to feel their questions was closed unfairly. The SE goes into a direction of a network of sites with narrow topics, in which the current central role of the stackoverflow will be only fossil.